# Mjpeg camera broadcaster on local network on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone-app

I need to get a live mjpeg stream from my ios phone camera to my computer, on the LAN. On Android there are some apps for creating an IP Webcam for creating a local IP Camera. Om iOS I can't find something free (without watermark). Do you know such an app?

Thanks!

PS: If there are solutions to this problem implying the use  of a Mac Computer, Mac Laptop or an iPad I don't have any of them, just an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Try

[IP Cam (IP Cam Pro)](http://www.senstic.com/iphone/ipcam/ipcam.aspx)

IP Cam turns your iOS device (iPhone, iPad, or iPod Touch) into a portable IP surveillance camera. Run IP Cam on your iOS device, and via Wi-Fi network, you can view live images captured by your iOS device's camera on web browser from any computer. You can even view IP Cam images from using Safari browser from another mobile device such as iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch.

[image]

[IP Camera Lite](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ip-camera-lite/id1013455241)

"IP Camera Lite" can turn your iOS device into a wireless IP Camera via built-in RTSP and HTTP Server for security monitoring with audio support, you can use your browser to view, of course, include "IP Camera", it can work with the 'IP Camera for Mac' via AirDrop.

[iCamViewer: CCTV Camera Pros](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/icamviewer-cctv-camera-pros/id346469891)

iCamViewer from CCTV Camera Pros is a free video surveillance viewer app that allows users to view up to 16 IP security cameras or CCTV cameras from your iPhone, iPod touch, or iPad from your local network or remotely over the Internet. This app works with both IP cameras and CCTV cameras. Please note that in order to work with CCTV cameras, your cameras must be connected to a compatible network surveillance DVR or network video server. This iPhone app does NOT generically work with all CCTV DVRs and IP cameras from all security manufacturers. The most up to date list of compatible cameras is available in the app.